# Documenting a project in a README.md and in a Wiki page?

Tags: documentation

I work on both frontend and backend applications and I still wonder how to document those applications.
When we start a development, we usually :

- Start a README.md that describes the application
- Create an internal wiki page that ... describes the application

The wiki page gives a visibility to people looking for information. Its search engine is frankly practical.
Yet, it's usually a sort of duplicate of the README.md.
We are certainly doing things wrong.

Can someone tell me what are the best practices to document a software ?

Thank you

Comment: Your best bet for this kind of question is to look at other applications, especially open source projects, and see how they are documented. Get some ideas then decide on your priorities and approach. Do something, then see how your audience responds.. This kind of question doesn't do well here. If you don't say what you are trying and what specific problem you encountered, it's hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, when software evolves over time, too detailed documentation in Wiki pages show a tendency that noone cares to bring them up-to-date, at least not in time. Two reasons I see are

- Wiki pages are often not versioned together with the source code / readme in the SCCS
- the responsibility for the Wiki is a often a shared one, whilst docs like "readme" files usually maintained by the developers who maintain also the software

Documentation which belongs to the software itself has at least a higher chance to be updated together with each new version of the software (of course, such documentation can also rot, but there should be some policies in your team to fight that).

Hence, my recommendation here is:

- use a Wiki only to maintain a high-level overview of your software, written on a level of abstraction that it does not require regular maintenance. One or two sentences about what a program is good for should be enough.
- any more detailed documentation belongs into documents which are part of the software itself
- the Wiki may contain hyperlinks to the newest documentation

That way, you avoid most of the duplication and combine the strengths of each media together.

Comment: Software is for code not documentation. If you have to branch/code review/deploy to change documentation you are doing something wrong. In fact, then no-one will do it as it's a pain and a potential risk to break somethings. Wiki and such are for documentation, where everything should live. repos are for code and functionality

Comment: @James: when you have a software with only one production system installed, with always the latest release, then using a Wiki can be fine. But when you have an off-the-shelve software which can be installed in several different versions by several different customers or users, you want to match documentation and software versions.  Otherwise your Wiki-docs will describe features or function which are in the newest version, but not available or working differently for the version the user hast installed.

Comment: The question states "internal wiki page" so I felt it was asking without 3rd party or external users, and it's unusual to run with different versions internally. If this is public and/or multiple versions then yes it needs all the documentation necessary in the README to be with the repo and each version.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the documentation as markdown files along with source code. Some great reasons why you should do this.

- Developers often `grep` the codebase for things(classes, functions, etc) they want to learn more about. If the docs are included in the codebase, the hits from the docs would also show up automatically when they do a grep.
- Similarly developers `grep` when they do refactoring. And including docs in the codebase make sure that they are not ignored during the refactoring.
- You can access and make changes to the docs even if you are offline.
- You are not tied to a third party service. You can generate HTML files from markdown files and host it anywhere.
- You can run tests for docs in CI. For example, make sure that the links in the docs are not broken.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which Version Control System, Wiki, and Project Management System you are using, so I will answer on that front:

[Fossil](https://fossil-scm.org/) calls itself an "SCM" but that can mean two things: "Software Configuration Management" or "Source Code Management" (the latter being basically a synonym for "Version Control System"). Fossil definitely leans towards the former: it was written *by* the author of SQLite *for* the development of SQLite. At first glance, it is a [distributed version control system](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/concepts.wiki) like Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, Monotone, Darcs, etc., but it is *so much more*.

It also does pretty much everything you would expect from a Project Management System like Jira or Redmine: [Issue Tracking](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/bugtheory.wiki), [Wiki](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/wikitheory.wiki), [Forum](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/forum.wiki), and a concept called "[technotes](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/event.wiki)" (basically a Wiki page that is addressed by a point in time instead of a name; this subsumes things like milestones, process steps, release notes, blog articles, etc.)

And it does all of this in a fully distributed fashion with support for forking, branching, merging, working offline, and all the other features you would expect from a distributed *VCS*, except it does it for your *entire project*, including issues, documentation, wiki, and so on.

And it does all of that with user accounts and access control … and that is *also* distributed.

A very promising entry into the same space was [Veracity](http://veracity-scm.com/), but development stopped in 2013.

Even if you don't use Fossil or a similar system, it is still possible to use Wikis which are stored inside the VCS. [Ikiwiki](https://ikiwiki.info/) used to be a popular one, but I am sure there are many, many others. Ikiwiki is VCS-agnostic, it is simply stored as files. A Git-aware Wiki could potentially do even cooler stuff such as using Git Notes, Git Attributes, etc.

The point being: maybe the problem you are having is caused by inadequate tools, not processes. It might not be possible to throw away your whole Project Management System and re-do it in Fossil, but maybe it is possible to move to an in-VCS Wiki, at least for the closely code-related documentation. This would solve the problem of code and Wiki being disconnected: they no longer are. (Essentially addressing the very first bullet point in [Doc Brown's excellent answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/415107/1352).)